# Route parameters coming through null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Not sure what I'm doing here but any and all parameters are coming through to my controller as `null` even though they are clearly defined in the rendered HTML.

**View**

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Export to Spreadsheet", "Export", "ZipCodeTerritory"
    , new {
       @searchZip = Model.searchZip,
       @searchActiveOnly = Model.searchActiveOnly,
       @searchTerritory = Model.searchTerritory,
       @searchState = Model.searchState
    })
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Export(string searchZip, bool? searchActiveOnly, string searchTerritory, string searchState)
    {
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<a href="/ZipCodeTerritory/Export?Length=16" searchactiveonly="True" searchstate="CA" searchterritory="" searchzip="">Export to Spreadsheet</a>
```

Comment: The @ in the parameter dictionary are not required and may be what is throwing this off.  Your rendered HTML is pretty broke for a URL which means it is the ActionLink helper that is not functioning properly.  It appears that ActionLink is changing your route parameters into `<a>` tag properties instead.  Try removing the @ in the `new {}` parts of your ActionLink

Comment: removed them and still no luck. also noticed that about the rendered link, however removing the `@` didn't happen to change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong overload for Html.ActionLink.  It's thinking that your route values are actually html attributes.  Additionally, you'll need to remove the "@"s in each of your variable names.  Try changing this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Spreadsheet", "Export", "ZipCodeTerritory"
, new {
   @searchZip = Model.searchZip,
   @searchActiveOnly = Model.searchActiveOnly,
   @searchTerritory = Model.searchTerritory,
   @searchState = Model.searchState
})
```

To this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Spreadsheet", "Export", "ZipCodeTerritory"
, new {
   searchZip = Model.searchZip,
   searchActiveOnly = Model.searchActiveOnly,
   searchTerritory = Model.searchTerritory,
   searchState = Model.searchState
}, null)
```

Comment: Additionally, one can move the controller into the RouteValue dictionary and then not need the null by using the Html.ActionLink(LinkTExt, Action, RouteValues) overload

Answer (score 1):

It is using the wrong overload, try this instead:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Spreadsheet", "Export", "ZipCodeTerritory"
    , 
     new {
       searchZip = Model.searchZip,
       searchActiveOnly = Model.searchActiveOnly,
       searchTerritory = Model.searchTerritory,
       searchState = Model.searchState
    }
    , null)
```